# Eclipse C/C++ Remote Debugging connection failed

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

i tried to apply a remote debugging session with Eclipse to a Windows XP remote pc. So i configured a Windows-Connection in "Debug Configuration" for a "C/C++ Remote Application". But it gives me the following Error message:

> "Daemon failed to launch server on IP_ADDRESS using port 0.
>
> Connection refused. Make sure that the DataStore daemon is running on
>   IP_ADDRESS"

What is the probleme here? Why is a "DataStore" needed, where to get it if it's necessary!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect, a RSE Server has to run on windows box. This invokes the necessary daemon which eclipse wants to connect to.

This was helpful: http://www.eclipse.org/tm/
Along with this guide: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.rse.doc.user/tasks/tbeginwindows.html